# Show log in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to show login Magento 2 of my custom module.

I have created an index controller but it's not working for me

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
protected $resultJsonFactory;
protected $_helper;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(Context $context, 
\Softprodigy\Opc\Helper\Data $helper,
\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->resultJsonFactory  = $resultJsonFactory;
    $this->_helper = $helper;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

  public function execute()
  {
    //die('dfsd');
    //$topTel = $this->_helper->getConfig('dynamicpdf/general/topTel');
    //$_thishepler = $this->_helper('namespace\moduename\Helper\Data'); 
    $isEnabled = $helper->getStoreConfig('namespace_module/general/enabled');

   $this->_logger->addDebug("test".$isEnabled); // log location: var/log/system.log
    $this->_logger->addInfo("test2".$isEnabled); // log location: var/log/exception.log
    $this->_logger->addNotice("test3".$isEnabled); // log location: var/log/exception.log
    $this->_logger->addError("test4".$isEnabled); // log location: var/log/exception.log
    $this->_logger->critical("test5".$isEnabled);
    print_r($isEnabled); die;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to log

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $_helper;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(Context $context, \Softprodigy\Opc\Helper\Data $helper,\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->resultJsonFactory  = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $isEnabled = $helper->getStoreConfig('namespace_module/general/enabled');

        $this->_logger->debug("test".$isEnabled); // log location: var/log/system.log
        $this->_logger->info("test2".$isEnabled); // log location: var/log/exception.log
        $this->_logger->notice("test3".$isEnabled); // log location: var/log/exception.log
        $this->_logger->error("test4".$isEnabled); // log location: var/log/exception.log
        $this->_logger->critical("test5".$isEnabled);
        print_r($isEnabled); die;
    }
}
```